# How to setup a Firebase demo project

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) mentions that the local emulator supports Real and Demo projects. A demo project is defined as:

> A demo project has no Firebase console configuration and no live resources.
> Demo project IDs have the demo- prefix.

The above mentions a demo- prefix but I can't find any examples of how that works. Is it possible to setup a demo project as specified in the above documentation without requiring a Firebase console project or any live resources?

Comment: I don't get this either. It sounds like there should be a way to add a demo project with `firebase use --add`. I've tried manually adding a demo project to `.firebaserc` to no avail.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can start the emulators with a demo project by using the `--project` flag:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --project demo-test --only auth
```

Just make sure that the project ID start with the `demo-` prefix. This line will produce the following output:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth
i  emulators: Detected demo project ID "demo-test", emulated services will use a demo configuration and attempts to access non-emulated services for this project will fail.
```

Comment: Do you have to init a project called demo-test first?

Comment: Ow good old google docs... adding this line avoids so much confusion...

Comment: This works like a charm, but note that you can no longer rely on the default project specified by `firebase use` and you need to specify the demo project on every CLI command (e.g. `firebase functions:shell --project demo-test`)

Comment: Where do you an API key to initialize the Firebase client library? Do you just make up a random one?

Comment: @aldel you can use a random one. I prefer to use a string `any` so it's clear that API key can be any non-empty string. Also don't forget to call `useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099)` in your code.

Comment: when i try this my cloud functions break: `functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on resource project demo-lendus.` but everything else works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create folder for project, initialize firebase with command **firebase init**. When initialization process ask you for project to use, select last option: **Don't set up a default project.**

I was got one error message at end of initialization process because region didn't set, but demo app should work fine.

Select what you need for project. After that go to file .firebaserc and write this into it:

```js
    {
         "projects": {
             "default": "demo-project"
          }
     }
```

I successfully ran firebase with:

```js
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
    import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase/firestore'

    const app = initializeApp({
         apiKey: 'any',
         authDomain: 'any',
         projectId: 'demo-project', // project name from .firebaserc
         storageBucket: 'any',
         messagingSenderId: 'any',
         appId: 'any',
    })
    export const db = getFirestore() // no need for app object here
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 8080)
```

Run emulators with: **firebase emulators:start**