# Firebase initializeApp with emulators without production config

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration

I am able to connect to Firebase firestore emulator from a `create-react-app` app locally using the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#android_apple_platforms_and_web_sdks). The example code simply includes a comment like this:

```
// Firebase previously initialized using firebase.initializeApp().
```

The [API reference for initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase#initializeapp) describes only one way of using it - by passing production configuration to `initializeApp` and that's the way I got it to work.

However, I am trying to run the app in a self-contained docker environment for the purpose of continuous integration. I do not want any config related to production in this version of the build. By production, I mean any reference that might count towards firebase billing. Is there a way to call `initializeApp` without production reference? Or are there other ways to handle CI builds?

Comment: No answer a year later?

Answer (score -1):

After some testing, you should initialize app with any string on apiKey:

```
initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'API KEY', // You can set any string here
  projectId: 'PROJECT ID HERE', // Optional, you can use here same from .firebaserc
})
```

Answer (score -2):

We need to use a demo app for this purpose, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68466383/5800527). Once we start the emulators described in that answer, `initializeApp` can be invoked like so:

```
initializeApp({
    projectId: "demo-test",
})
```

The projectId used in here need to match the one used when starting up the emulator and it needs to start with `demo`. This ensures there is no way for the app to connect to production services accidentally.

**Update after downvotes:**

I reviewed my project [here](https://github.com/andrewnessinjim/firebase-react-todo) and it works. Here's the config I have used:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    projectId: "demo-react-todo",
    apiKey: "dummy-key-for-emulator"
};
```

This should address the problems in the comments. I failed to mention that we can use a random apiKey and the emulators don't care. Please note the version that worked for me is `9.6.10`.

Comment: This throws `missing-api-key` firebase error. It looks like `initializeApp` does require a full configuration.

Comment: this does not work for me, it outputs "FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)."